# Running matlab code from c# front end

Tags: c#, matlab

I have images return from matlab to c# front end and want to display them using c# but cannot display them as they are retured as object. Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the MatLab code that returns the image, and place a break point in your C# program after the image was received. Then look at the Object in the debugger and post exactly which type is packaged inside the Object object. That way one can maybe find out how to convert it. Also, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If The object you receive from the matlab is an Image, a Bitmap, or a BitmapImage, which are C# objects you can just cast them.

```
Image img = (Image)MyfunctionreturningImageAsObject();
```

otherwise can you specify:
In What format are the Images returned?
What C# frontend are You using?
Winforms, WPF, Asp.Net?

in that case we can be more specific.

Comment: I am using Winforms and the return from matlab is 2 images which in c# recieved as objects i want to store them to database and i also want to display them type of images is logical i.e. binary

Comment: You can try the cast to Image or to Bitmap as I wrote above to see if the Object is really an Image simply returned as object.
If the object is not an image but a Byte Array, you can try a conversion using a memory stream and the Bitmap class in the GDI+ try the first and if you not succeed, you can search here for Convert Byte Array to Bitmap to try the second thing. Or ask :)